# How can $f$ and $g$ be inverses even though they are not surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Lay - Analysis With An Introduction to Proof 4th Edition

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Why not

$$f: [0,\infty) \to [1,\infty)$$
$$g: [1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$$

?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Yes, that is Example 7,26 (also Fig. 7.7).  Both $f$ and $g$ are surjective on their respective ranges.

Comment: @hardmath It says the codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$. It is NOT surjective with all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk:  The OP says $f:[0,\infty)\to [1,\infty)$ and $g:[1,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$.  In that connection certainly both are surjective and $f\circ g$ is the identity on $[1,\infty)$ while $g\circ f$ is the identity on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @hardmath But the book doesn't have those codomains. If the codomains are as the OP wrote, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. A function needs to be surjective (also injective) to be invertible. You just have to be more careful with the domains/ranges to make them invertible, the book is being sloppy.

The functions are surjective with their range (which is always the case). But the domains and codomains should be what you wrote.